# Lagrange Multipliers and Lambda

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

We know that:

> The upshot of all this is the following: at a local maximum, the gradient of $f$ and the gradient of $g$ are pointing in the same direction. In other words, they are proportional. In other words, there's some constant $\lambda$ such that the gradient of $f$ is  $\lambda$ times the gradient of $g$. That's it. This $\lambda$ is your Lagrange multiplier.

Why is it that $\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g$, not $\lambda \nabla f = \nabla g?$

If $\nabla f $ is proportinal to $\nabla g$, that is to say that $\nabla g$ is proportional to $\nabla f$. So what's stopping us from placing lambda in front of $\nabla f$?

Comment: Just convention; nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember "λ" is defined to be a constant.
And as such either 1/λ and λ has no specified differences.
Say in your case ∇f=λ∇g. If we let λ' = λ, its correct to establish λ'∇f=∇g

Besides there is one little reminder, in order to prevent confusion. We usually retain the habit of using  **∇f=λ∇g**  when we look for the **extreme points of   'f'**